# Wordpress Themify Ultra Issue with Safari First Loading

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, overlapping

Helping this client with this safari issue on this website - http://triwivesclub.com.

It appears that when you first time load the home page, there is some overlapping article boxes and when you refresh it,  it fixes itself.  Would need help how to fix this.  You will have to flush cache everytime to produce this issue.

[Overlapping image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulylg.png)